# cuando uso join me omite muchos registros usando eloquent con laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

Estoy presentando un inconveniente referente a una consulta eloquent con laravel, el problema es que cuando uso el select directo me trae todos los registros normal sin problema, pero al momento de usar join para traer en éste caso traigo municipios y departamentos solo me trae algunos (no todos) los registros por ejemplo la la ciudad(municipio) medellin no me lo trae en el cuando hago el join. no se que estará mal ayuda porfa.

```
$ciudades = DB::table('municipios')
                ->Where('municipio','LIKE',"$request->question%")
                ->get();
```

este es el resultado de esta consulta... me muestra normal, pero como quiero que me muestre el departamento necesito hacer join.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando hago el join

```
$ciudades =  DB::table('municipios')
              ->join('departamentos','municipios.departamento_id','=','departamentos.id_departamento')
              ->Where('municipio','LIKE',"$request->question%")
              ->get();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me llega a mostrar resultados pero me omite muchos entre esos uno de los registros que más necesito y se consultará mucho.

Comment: Puede ser que algunos municipios no tengan departamentos es por ello que el al hacer el join no encuentra valores, puedes probar reemplazando tu `join` por un `leftJoin`

Comment: ¿Algún motivo en particular para no utilizar Eloquent?

Comment: No, no hay inconviente solo que no se mucho de los usos que le puedo dar a las consultas en laravel aprendí con esa.

Comment: @AníbalJorqueraCornejo claro, es correcto lo que me dices efectivamente no se encuentra el departamento correspondiente, intente con leftjoin y me los muestra y claro ahi el problema, Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Si te da lo mismo que alguno municipios no tengan departamentos usa leftjoin. https://donnierock.com/2014/03/04/diferencia-entre-inner-join-left-join-y-right-join-sql/